# searching needle when we know the haystack in sql

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-2

I have a database of many country codes with their corresponding country names
for example:

```
mauritius   230
canada      1
testcountry 1234
```

each country may have between 1 to 5 starting number. The user will enter any phone number for example 23012345678 and the output should be `mauritius`.

How can I perform such sql lookup in the database? I was thinking that I could make 5 substring of the input data:

```
2
23
230
2301
23012
```

and find a match, however this is not efficient. Any idea how to proceed?
(php)

Comment: Do you have a list of calling codes used in the world? Have you thought about how you could solve this? Have you tried anything yet? We are not here to do the work for you, you know.

Comment: yes i already have a database of all country codes, and i am alrady geting the answer when i perform something like this . first i make a search with substring 2% if the answer is not = 1 then i search 23% then 230% then 2301% untill the answer is 1 row found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a like query by matching your code column with phone number by using a wild card after column so it will match only starting characters

```
select *
from countries
where '23012345678' like concat(`code`,'%') > 0
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6ebc/1)

**Edit from comments**

You can use `length()` function on your code column and order results with highest length for most matched country code

```
select *
from countries
where '23012345678' like concat(`code`,'%') > 0
order by length(`code`) desc 
limit 1
```

[`DEMO 2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/304b22/2)

Comment: hello this is very helpful. however i tried editing it and added a test country with code 2301, now the response is coming with 2 country. does exist a way where i can have the answer with the most match?  like if i have 230 mauritius and 2301 testcountry then i take 2301 ?

Comment: @RajneeshKumarGobin you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking tick option